# How can I convert JSON String to Numbers?

Tags: json, api, flutter, dart

I am facing a problem, I want to get a JSON response like id as `int`, but JSON response I am getting numbers into String, is there any way to convert String into numbers using `Dart` because I can not make changes in the API? I am getting a JSON response like [this](http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees).

Comment: can you send the way you stored your data to your app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help,

```
class Employee {
  int id;
  String employeeName;
  double employeeSalary;
  int employeeAge;
  String profileImage;

  Employee({
    this.id,
    this.employeeName,
    this.employeeSalary,
    this.employeeAge,
    this.profileImage,
  });

  factory Employee.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Employee(
        id: int.parse(json["id"]),
        employeeName: json["employee_name"],
        employeeSalary: double.parse(json["employee_salary"]),
        employeeAge: int.parse(json["employee_age"]),
        profileImage: json["profile_image"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id.toString(),
        "employee_name": employeeName,
        "employee_salary": employeeSalary.toString(),
        "employee_age": employeeAge.toString(),
        "profile_image": profileImage,
      };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can parse with [`int.parse` method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/int/parse.html)

```dart
void main() {
  String myStringNumber = '123456';

  int myNumber = int.parse(myStringNumber);

  print(myNumber);
}
```